# jQuery - Get element from array and enter in each consecutive td in same order

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array which contains the ranks of three items.[0: 3 1: 2 2: 1] Each 'rank' needs to be entered into each consequent 'td' in the row in the same order as they are present in the array.

This is the code that I'm using, but it's throwing only rank '1' for all the tds.

```
 jQuery('#divResult table tbody tr td').each(function ($) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) { 
        if (jQuery(this).text() == 'Ranking') jQuery(this).nextAll("td").each(function ($) {
            jQuery(this).empty().html('<div>' + ranks[i] + '</div>');   
        });
    };
 });
```

I understand the error must be with the way I have defined the index but I'm not sure where is the error. Please help.

Complete fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mithunu/skt47yeb/3/

Snippet:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var StatJSON = {
   "Samsung": {
    "Ranking": '',
    "Rating": 2.5,
    },
  "Mi": {
    "Ranking": '',
    "Rating": 3.5,
    },
  "Apple": {
    "Ranking": '',
    "Rating": 4.5,
    },
};

jQuery('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
 var data = [];  
 jQuery("#selection").find(':selected').each(function(e) {
   var this_input = jQuery(this);
   if (this_input.is(':selected')) {
     data.push(this_input.val());
   }
 });
 $('#divResult').empty().append(PrintTable(data));

 jQuery('#divResult table tbody tr').find("td:first").each(function ($) {
        jQuery(this).addClass(((this.textContent).replace(/[()]/g, '')).replace(/ /g, ''));
        jQuery(this).siblings('td').addClass(((this.textContent).replace(/[()]/g, '')).replace(/ /g, ''));
        jQuery(this).parent('tr').addClass(((this.textContent).replace(/[()]/g, '')).replace(/ /g, ''));
    });

 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = []
    jQuery('tr.Rating > td:not(:first)').each(function(){
        var element = jQuery(this).text();
        data.push(element);
    });
    var sorted = data.slice().sort(function(a,b){return b-a})
    var ranks = data.slice().map(function(v){ return sorted.indexOf(v)+1 });
    console.log(ranks);

 jQuery('#divResult table tbody tr td').each(function ($) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) { 
        if (jQuery(this).text() == 'Ranking') jQuery(this).nextAll("td").each(function ($) {
            jQuery(this).empty().html('<div>' + ranks[i] + '</div>');   
        });
    };
 });
});
});

function PrintTable(data) {
  var html = '<table id="compTable" class="compTable"><tr><td>';
  if (data && data.length) {
    html += '</td>';
    jQuery.each(data, function(k, v) {
      html += '<th id="myHeader" class="header2">' + v + '</th>';
    });
    html += '</tr>';
    jQuery.each(StatJSON[data[0]], function(k, v) {
      html += '<tr><td>' + k + '</td>';
        jQuery.each(data, function(k2, v2) {
        html += '<td>' + StatJSON[data[k2]][k] + '</td>';
      });
      html += '</tr>';
    });
  } else { html += 'No results found</td></tr>'; }
  html += '</table>';
  return html;
}

});
```

```css
.compTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
Options:
<select id="selection" select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
        <option value="Mi">Mi</option>
        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<input id="btnSubmit" class="button" type="submit" value="submit"/>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="divResult" class="divResult"></div>
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"Complete fiddle here"* Please put the [mcve] **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). *(Edit: I've done it for you this time.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the row (instead of each cell) and then check if the first child of that row is "Ranking". If so iterate the other children:

```
jQuery('#divResult table tbody tr').each(function () {
    var $td = $(this).children();
    if ($td.eq(0).text() == 'Ranking') {
        for (var i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) { 
            $td.eq(i+1).empty().append($('<div>').text(ranks[i]));
        }
    }
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var StatJSON = {
    "Samsung": {
      "Ranking": '',
      "Rating": 2.5,
    },
    "Mi": {
      "Ranking": '',
      "Rating": 3.5,
    },
    "Apple": {
      "Ranking": '',
      "Rating": 4.5,
    },
  };

  jQuery('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    var data = [];
    jQuery("#selection").find(':selected').each(function(e) {
      var this_input = jQuery(this);
      if (this_input.is(':selected')) {
        data.push(this_input.val());
      }
    });
    $('#divResult').empty().append(PrintTable(data));

    jQuery('#divResult table tbody tr').find("td:first").each(function($) {
      jQuery(this).addClass(((this.textContent).replace(/[()]/g, '')).replace(/ /g, ''));
      jQuery(this).siblings('td').addClass(((this.textContent).replace(/[()]/g, '')).replace(/ /g, ''));
      jQuery(this).parent('tr').addClass(((this.textContent).replace(/[()]/g, '')).replace(/ /g, ''));
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var data = []
      jQuery('tr.Rating > td:not(:first)').each(function() {
        var element = jQuery(this).text();
        data.push(element);
      });
      var sorted = data.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
        return b - a
      })
      var ranks = data.slice().map(function(v) {
        return sorted.indexOf(v) + 1
      });
      console.log(JSON.stringify(ranks));

      jQuery('#divResult table tbody tr').each(function() {
        var $td = $(this).children();
        if ($td.eq(0).text() == 'Ranking') {
          for (var i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
            $td.eq(i + 1).empty().append($('<div>').text(ranks[i]));
          }
        }
      });

    });
  });

  function PrintTable(data) {
    var html = '<table id="compTable" class="compTable"><tr><td>';
    if (data && data.length) {
      html += '</td>';
      jQuery.each(data, function(k, v) {
        html += '<th id="myHeader" class="header2">' + v + '</th>';
      });
      html += '</tr>';
      jQuery.each(StatJSON[data[0]], function(k, v) {
        html += '<tr><td>' + k + '</td>';
        jQuery.each(data, function(k2, v2) {
          html += '<td>' + StatJSON[data[k2]][k] + '</td>';
        });
        html += '</tr>';
      });
    } else {
      html += 'No results found</td></tr>';
    }
    html += '</table>';
    return html;
  }

});
```

```css
.compTable {
  table - layout: fixed;
  width: 100 %;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  font - family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans - serif;
  margin: 10 px;
  border: 1 px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Options:
<select id="selection" select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
  <option value="Mi">Mi</option>
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<input id="btnSubmit" class="button" type="submit" value="submit" />
<br /><br />
<div id="divResult" class="divResult"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @trincot ! Thanks for taking the time & effort out!! :) I updated the code but the 'Rank' row is coming blank. :( Still not sure where I'm going wrong. Find updated fiddle for your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/mithunu/skt47yeb/5/

Comment: You are using `$` as parameter. Please remove that in your callbacks.

Comment: Hi!! Sorry, my bad! I changed it to the following: ```` jQuery('#divResult table tbody tr').each(function ($) {
    var td = jQuery(this).children();
    if ((td.eq(0)).text == 'Ranking') {
        for (var i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) { 
            $td.eq(i+1).empty().append($('<div>').text(ranks[i]));
        }
    }
}); ```` but the Rank td is still blank. Would it be possible for you to edit the fiddle included?? : https://jsfiddle.net/mithunu/skt47yeb/8/ Thanks again!!!

Comment: But just take the version I posted here? Don't do `function($)`, just `function()`.